# Why we firstly make repository and then services and again from repository we implements services ? Please check the code you'll understand?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

```
public interface CrudRepository{
  Test createThis(Test t);
}

@Repository
public class TestCrud implements CrudRepository{
   public Test createThis(Test t)
{
     //implementation 
}
```

}

---

Now the service interface and implementation

```
   public interface CrudService{
     Test createThis(Test t);
   }
```

@Service
public class TestService implements CrudService{

```
    @AutoWired
    CrudRepository crudR;

    public Test createThis(Test t){
           crudR.createThis(t)
    }
```

}

When we use to develop web project with spring first we do interface then we implement in repository than 
we do again interface and from repository we implement the service . Again the same why don't we use directly the
 repository in controller but we do this ? I hope that someone can explain to me

Comment: you can switch from one repository to the other.. similarly you can switch from one service to the other. what's the problem?

Comment: It isolates your controllers from the repository, allowing you to e.g. switch out database technologies without rewriting the whole backend app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason is "flexibility". In your case the service doesn't know from where data comes right? And it doesn't have to. It only knows that there is repository which will give some data. Services shouldn't know where the date are saved. It could be in file, database or in memory. Another goal is that if you have app in which you save data in file and you want to switch to database. You only need to write new repository layer which will know about database and you don't need to switch a single row of code in your service layer. This is the main goal when you write big application.

If you do not understand me you can read about Open closed principle : http://www.oodesign.com/open-close-principle.html

Comment: yes thanks i think now i understood the difference of repository and service because in so many tutorial i saw just a little things and were same and i was confused on those . Thanks again wish you the best :))